# Docker NodeJS MongoDB "catch { } // eslint-disable-line ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker

I can not built my project with Docker

I write the command **docker-compose up**, but at the end I got an error connected with mongoDB;

*Error:*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W77RW.jpg)

*package.json*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaOtE.png)

*Dockerfile* [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpaKx.png)

*docker-compose.yml* [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXuEh.png)

Comment: Could you add your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file to the question?

Comment: On the first line of the Dockerfile, try for example `FROM node:16-alpine` instead of the older node verion.

Comment: Please post your files as text, not links to screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Your node version is way to old. You need to choose a node version that supports catch without a variable:

```
try {
   ...
} catch { }
```

vs

```
try {
   ...
} catch (e) { }
```

Node's currenct LTS version is: 16.15.0: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Do You mean node on my pc? On my pc i have v18.1.0

Comment: Your docker file references an image with node 8.11.2